# how to simulate high CPU usage on android device

Tags: android

As the question clearly states, I want to simulate high CPU usage for some time, to any given percentage, preferably without any 3rd party application. I'm trying to simulate this to run a few automated test cases through adb/monkeyrunner when the CPU usage is high. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: what if you just try run an infinite loop there?

Answer (score 5):

You can't simulate. You can actually increment CPU usage by writing some intensive application which includes lot of math etc. There are also benchmarks which stress the CPU to 100% utilization. You can take a reference from them as well.